# Why does the DOM single-origin policy take into account protocol and port? What if it was just domain?

Tags: http, same-origin-policy

I'm learning the basics of network security and am trying to really understand the single origin policy. I was wondering what the vulnerabilities would be if an origin was only defined by domain, as opposed to the normal trio of scheme, domain, host. I know it would be more insecure, but how exactly?

My thinking was, for protocol, the dangers of sending/receiving data from an https page to an http one, since when something coming from the http page wouldn't be encrypted and could be read by someone monitoring network traffic. I'm not really sure if that's correct reasoning or not, or if I'm missing something.

As for the need for the port in origin definition, I don't really have any ideas.

So again, why exactly would defining an origin solely by domain be vulnerable? What could happen if that were the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS vs. HTTP would be a very big deal, because HTTP doesn't authenticate the server and therefore you have no idea who you're talking to. Suppose you're using your bank or whatever via HTTPS. Everything is secure. But there's a network attacker who has a man-in-the-middle position on your connection. As soon as your browser (perhaps in another tab) makes any plain HTTP request, the attacker intercepts the response and injects into it a hidden iframe for the HTTP version of your bank's site. Your browser sends this HTTP request, and the attacker intercepts the request - not even letting it go to the real server - and spoofs the server, sending a fake response that contains some malicious script. Your browser executes that script, which sends requests (over HTTPS, so that `Secure` cookies are included) to the real server. Because the browser considers only domain when determining origin, the script-initiated request is considered same-origin, and therefore unrestricted; the attacker can make nigh-arbitrary requests, and see the responses, allowing the attacker total compromise of your account without anything being visible to you.

Cross-port same-domain attacks would be rarer, but they can still happen. A classic example would be development systems, where there's often multiple servers running. The others may expose sensitive internal data, management APIs, or even allow remote control over the server (via a debug interface), and the server may also be a workstation where a browser is in use. In this case, an attacker might pull a similar attack to the above, but rather than attacking the user's session on the public app, they launch cross-port attacks on the other services. Since it's again considered same origin, the attacker would be able to send arbitrary requests and read the responses. In essence, using CSRF to pivot inside a firewall, except with an extra attack step but full ability to control requests and read responses (which will defeat all CSRF prevention measures).

An alternative way that cross-port can be dangerous is if a single machine is hosting multiple servers that don't mutually trust one another. For example, you might have a system where there's one sensitive authenticated server that has privileged access of some sort, and one malicious but sandboxed app that also runs a server. If the user is authenticated to the privileged service, but also browses to the sandboxed one, that sandboxed server could return malicious script that attacks the privileged service, accessing sensitive data or taking privileged access, once again with full access because the script and its requests are considered same-origin as the target.

It's worth noting that HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) mitigates the cross-protocol attack, but only addresses some cross-port attacks; even an untrustworthy server can still serve HTTPS traffic, in which case it's probably some-protocol as the target server.